# Foreign key -- id or just UNIQUE column

Tags: mysql, sql

Suppose that I have a table with the following columns:

```
CREATE TABLE users
{
  id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
  login VARCHAR(50) UNIQUE,
  password VARCHAR(50)
}
```

And I need to create a table which will store one cookie for each account. What's better -- to create a foreign key that refers to the `login` column from the first table

```
CREATE TABLE cookies
{
  id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
  cookie VARCHAR(50),
  login VARCHAR(50) FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES users(login)
}
```

or to create a foreign key that refers to the `id` column?

```
CREATE TABLE cookies
{
  id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
  cookie VARCHAR(50),
  expires DATETIME,
  id_user INTEGER FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES users(id)
}
```

And why?

Comment: I prefer to match the FK of Users(id), that the best way.

Comment: What is the purpose of cookie column? It is one column or several columns in cookie table? Is it one row in cookie table per user? Or there may be several?  What if you add that column in users table directly?

Comment: If memory serves, at least in sql server, you must use the primary key at least in one side of the foreign key constraint (in one to one both sides should be the primary key)

Comment: Which RDBMS is this for? Please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Comment: @Giorgi Nakeuri Edited. "It is one columns or several columns in cookie table?" -- several, like cookie itself and expiration date. "Is it one row in cookie table per user?" -- yep

Comment: @ZoharPeled: actually, your memory serves you incorrectly - in SQL Server, a foreign key can *also* references a column (or set of columns) with a **unique index** on them (not just a primary key)

Comment: @marc_s Does it matter? I'm just thinking about the structure of tables. Most likely it'll be MySQL, edited

Comment: @Chandru Why do you think so?

Comment: @FrozenHeart: yes, it matters, because the **SQL** language standard leaves a lot of details out, and the various vendors fill those gaps with different solutions, so in one RDBMS you might be able to do something (like referencing a **unique index** in SQL Server) that another system doesn't support

Comment: @marc_s Ok, I see. So?

Comment: @marc_s thanks. I wasn't sure I remember correctly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok as you have several columns in cookie table and since that is a seperate entity I agree and it makes sense to take those additional columns in seperate table. What about pks and fks? Since you have only one row per user I would make `userid` a `primary key` and `foreign key` simultaneously:

```
cookies
{
  id_user(pk, fk), 
  cookie,
  expires
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! How could I add a row about specific user to this table then?

Comment: First you add row to users table, and then to coocie table. It is a little bit unclear what is the problem to add row to table?

Comment: @FrozenHeart, yes that's exactly what I mean

Comment: Why did you decide to just use one column instead of two separate columns?

Comment: @FrozenHeart, because in this case you would have extra column and extra space used. No need when it is possible without it. You could have id and userid columns as well. Id pk and userid fk and unique index.

Comment: And what about `VARCHAR(50) FOREIGN KEY`? Is it an option at all or is it considered a bad practice?

Comment: It may be an option. Why not? Depends on case. But it is a big topic. You can ask another question about it.

Answer (score 1):

```
CREATE TABLE cookies
{
  id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
  cookie VARCHAR(50),
  login VARCHAR(50) FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES users(login)
}
```

I think this is better option, as you need to communicate with `login`.

Comment: Please note that in MySQL, this line: `login VARCHAR(50) FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES users(login)` will **not create a FOREIGN KEY**. The column will be there but the FK definition will be sadly and rather silently ignored.

Answer (score 1):

Use a foreign key that relates to the primary key of the users table:

```
create a foreign key that refers to the id column?

CREATE TABLE cookies
(
    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    cookie VARCHAR(50),
    expires DATETIME,
    user_id INTEGER,
    FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES users(id)
)
```

The reason for doing this as a general convention is that the users(id) primary key is an immutable value. The 'login' column or any other which represents meta data about an object external to the database may change over time and is therefore less suitable for use in foreign key references.

Comment: Please note that in MySQL, this line: `id_user INTEGER FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES users(id)` will **not create a FOREIGN KEY**. The column will be there but the FK definition will be sadly and rather silently ignored.

Comment: No, inline foreign key definitions are ignored, in all engines. You need to define the foreign key separately. See: **[Using Foreign Key and References for ON DELETE CASCADE in mysql](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/14070/using-foreign-key-and-references-for-on-delete-cascade-in-mysql/14086#14086)**

Comment: Ah well spotted, I have removed my comment. You could clarify your comment to show how to do foreign keys correctly as it would help answer the question better.